# Handling extglob in library scripts that are sourced at login

Tags: bash

Having posted a question about debugging a bash script, the solution involved setting the command `shopt -s extglob`.

I have been sourcing some library scripts at login for use interactively.  I introspected the possibility of calling `shopt -s extglob` at the beginning of each file and unsetting at the end of each file.

It was explained that I could use the current status of a shopt flag.  The command `shopt -p extglob` also outputs a string one can eval to get back the current setting.

Can I get some further elaborations and some tests and useful implementations I can check out?

Comment: Since you are talking only about a setup for **interactive** shells, did you consider leaving _extglob_ turned on permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code would look something like this:

```
savestate=$(shopt -p extglob) # save old extglob setting
shopt -s extglob # enable extglob
# do something that requires extended globbing
eval "$savestate" # restore the old extglob setting
```

You could put the first two lines at the beginning of the script, and the last line at the end. The rest of the script would be the "do something" part.

Comment: So you really do not simply do `shopt -s extglob` and end with `shopt -u extglob`.

Comment: @Bennings That's not safe if the calling script has already enabled extglob, because it will disable it.

Comment: What do you mean by `calling script`.  Would you be so kind to show me a small example about how it will be disabled?

Comment: You said this was for a script that you call with `source scriptname`. The calling shell is the one that contains that command.

Comment: Isn't this what you were looking for instead of just setting it at the beginning of the script and unsetting at the end? It seemed like you didn't understand how to use `shopt -p extglob` to solve the problem, this shows how to do it.

Comment: I have a function in a script that sources several files from the library.

Comment: Right, and each of those library files should use the above code, so that they don't affect the `extglob` setting of the original script.

Comment: I understand this time round.

Answer (score 0):

> I introspected the possibility of calling shopt -s extglob at the beginning of each file and unsetting at the end of each file.

You could write a `function`, something like:

```
enable_extlob(){ 
  if ! shopt -q extglob; then
    shopt -s extglob
  fi
}

disable_extglob(){
  if shopt -q extglob; then
    shopt -u extglob
  fi
}
```

---

For both start and end of the script/files, something like

```
extglob_boolean(){ 
  if ! shopt -q extglob; then
     shopt -s extglob
  else
    shopt -u extglob
  fi
}
```

---

- Add that at the beginning and at the end of your script/files.
- The function checks if extglob is NOT on, enable it otherwise disable it.
- The downside of this is if the script you're calling needs `extglob` like what @Barmar said from his comment post. So make sure you *really* need this.

Comment: There's no need to check whether it's already on or not. There's no harm in enabling it if it's already enabled.

Comment: @Barmar, not from this side, especially from the root user. Also there is no harm on checking it also.

Comment: No harm, but no point. Just do `shopt -s extglob`. But the problem the OP has is that they want to leave `extglob` unchanged when the script finishes. Your code doesn't do that.

Comment: Right, I just answered what the OP posted. If i remeber correctly there was a bug from enabling extglob if it is already on, maybe not but yeah, will have to ask the op.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Some people would want to conform with POSIX on their scripts.

Comment: There was a bug because I needed to enable `extglob` for a case statement, and it was off.

Comment: @Bennings, right so either way, you need to choose which answer is best for your needs.